# Angular6 - Read response body of text/plain

Tags: angular, post, response, angular2-observables

I am performing a sign-up action and in my backend when the user successfully registers I return his id e.g. "105" and when the register fails (user already exists) I return "USER_EXISTS". I have checked the request on Postman and the body of the response is correct.
In both cases, I return "plain/text".

However, I am not able to find how to get the body of the response through the Observable object that I get return.

In register.component.ts:

```
userExists = "";
onSubmit() {

    const newUser : RegisterUser = {  email: this.register.email,
                                  password: this.register.password,
                                  firstName: this.register.firstName,
                                  lastName: this.register.lastName,
                                  phoneNumber: this.register.phoneNumber}


    this.registerService.addUser(newUser)
    .subscribe(response => (this.userExists = response)); //The purpose of this line is to get the body of the text/plain response and assign it into the this.userExists string
}
```

In RegisterService.service.ts

```
addUser (registerUser) {

    return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + "User/add", registerUser, httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default angular 6 produce **JSON** reponse
if you want text/plain you should set **responseType** as **'text'**

```
 addUser (registerUser) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + "User/add", {responseType: 'text'});
 }
```

try to append it in **httpOptions**

check it [**text/plain**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rh7r9f?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1):

In RegisterService.service.ts, add map and convert response to text as below:

addUser (registerUser) {

```
return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + "User/add", registerUser, httpOptions).map(res => res.text());
```

}

Comment: I converted it to this line:  
    `return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + "User/add", registerUser, httpOptions).pipe(map((response: any) => response.text()));  `
 
since the code you posted I think is not compatible with my version of rxjs (or I am failing with the imports).

However, I receive the following error in the console: 
`ERROR TypeError: response.text is not a function`

Comment: Please add below to import map from rxjs: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: It still returns a compile error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>' which was the reason that I used the .pipe