# Text Response from Spring REST API endpoint, how to retrieve that on Angular Front end

Tags: json, angular, typescript, spring-rest

Spring REST API is responding with following response:

- On successful execution : It returns me a response of Text type.
- On unsuccessful execution : It returns me JSON error object.

Front-End Service Class :

```
private detailsURL = 'http://localhost:8080/register';

constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

register(regisDetails): Observable<any>{
   return this.http.post(this.detailsURL,regisDetails);
}
```

Front-End Component Class:

```
registerUser(){
   this.service.register(this.regisForm.value).subscribe(
     success => this.successMessage = success,
     error => this.errorMessage = error.error.errorMessage
   );
}
```

In case of error I'm getting the error message I'm supposed to get. But in case of success I'm not getting the successMessage.

Just wanted to know if there's any way to fetch the Text type response on front end. Or else I'll have to change my backend to send response of JSON Type for successful execution as well.

Please help me understand this thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular http post request content type from 'text/plain' to 'application/json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669615/angular-http-post-request-content-type-from-text-plain-to-application-json)

Comment: Even this should be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900264/angular6-read-response-body-of-text-plain

Comment: Yeah by changing the response type in return staement it works.  `return this.http.post(this.detailsURL,regisDetails,{responseType:'text'});`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the status for your response. In the controller part you have to mention consumes="application/json" in api request.

Comment: You mean to say produces = "application/json" on  @PastMapping in Spring REST API. Right? I tried that thing it send JSON type data but how to access that on front end ? As it doesn't have key value pair. It has only some Text. Like "Successful Registration"

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing your changes at the backend and provide the response in Json format response for both the success and backend. That would be the ideal solution.

It is really a bad design to provide a different response than what is expected. You could check the value of the header in request "accept:application/json" and provide response as was expected by the front end

Front End Fix :
However, in the front end you could always use
JSON.parse(success) to convert the text to Json object and use it further as required.

Comment: success => this.successMessage = JSON.parse(success)

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't work as well